# Are the manga and the anime portraying Beerus as having the same strenght compared to other gods?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last manga chapter of Dragon Ball Super,

> We've seen Beerus fights all the other gods together against him and do pretty well, and he and Kitela remains as the last standing up in an exhition match where all gods were present.

But in the anime, we never see this, plus when Beerus and Champa fight each other they seem to be in the same level, and when Goku shows his Ultra Instinct state or transformation, almost all gods who participate in the tournament are sweating (except for Mosco who can't sweat because it's a robot) but those in the top 4 are worried but not sweating (this could have to do with the fact they arent participating in the tournament too, but I thought it could be because Goku could be a threat to themselves too). Plus I dont remember if something was directly stated, but for some reason I assumed the 4 gods who were left out of the tournament were the 4 strongest gods of destruction (specially Geene who refused to participate in the exhibition match of the anime I assumed he was the strongest of all) . Therefore, my question is,

are the manga and the anime portraying Beerus as having the same strenght compared to other gods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well firstly, you have made a couple of incorrect assumptions which need to be clarified.

1. The reason you see all the Gods shocked and surprised once goku uses ultra instinct is because this a technique which even a god can't master perfectly and this was mastered a mere mortal. We have seen this inferiority complex shown by the gods towards the mortals multiiple times whenever they are astonished with a mortal's strength. We even see Sidra and Belmod shocked when goku turns SSJB. This is because of the mortal having the powers of a god.
2. Beerus is stronger than Champa both in the anime and in the manga. This was stated explicitely by Vados. That doesn't imply Champa is weak by any means. Also the fight between Beerus and Champa wasn't really an actual fight between 2 gods of destructions. Neither of them were utilising any of their skills and it was more or less like 2 angry kids throwing a fit and punching each other.
3. In the manga, Beerus is indicated to be a lot stronger than most of the god's of destructions(Including those of the high mortal ranking universes). So In the manga at least we could conclude Beerus is among the top 3 or at least, top 5 strongest gods of destructions across the multiverse.
4. As far as the anime goes, Gene not taking part in the intial match doesn't necessarily for a fact indicate that he is the strongest. It might be for a number of reasons. Perhaps, he knew the grand priest would have them fix up the damages or perhaps  the match would be very destructive and not be concluded or maybe there was another god among those 3 who was the strongest of the 4 and he knew that he would end up winning.
5. You do bring up an interesting point about the gods of the higher mortal ranking universes not seeming as nervous compared to the gods of the one's taking part in the tournament. However, like you said , it could possibly be because they aren't taking part in the tournament of power or maybe they have mastered the technique already.

What we do know for a fact is Jiren is as at the least as strong as Beerus or possibly even stronger.